# Sending and recieving data to and from server sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I hava a server socket and a client socket.I have created a buffered input and output stream for both the sockets.I have established a connection between them .Now i have sent data from the client socket to the server socket via the BufferedOutputStream and have read it from the server socket and displayed it .When i tried to send the data back to the client socket it throws exception saying the socket is closed .
Here is the code
Server application code:

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyServer 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int c;
        ServerSocket myServer=new ServerSocket(4341);
        Socket cSocket;
        cSocket =myServer.accept();     
        System.out.println("connection made");
        InputStream in = cSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = cSocket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        while ((c=bin.read())!=-1)
        {   
            //c=in.read();
            System.out.println((char)c);
            bout.write(c);
            //System.out.print("junaid");
        }
        System.out.println("connection made");
        bout.flush();
        cSocket.shutdownOutput();
        cSocket.close();
        myServer.close();
    }
}
```

Client application:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
public class IOStreams
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int c;
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",4341);
        InputStream in=s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String myStr="what is google";
        byte buf[] = myStr.getBytes();
        try
        {
            bout.write(buf);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        bout.flush();
        //InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        //OutputStream out =s.getOutputStream();        
        s.shutdownOutput();
        while((c=bin.read()) !=-1)
        {
            //System.out.print("junaid");
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        //System.out.println(a);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i only read from the server sockets input stream it works fine but when i also try to read from the client socket's input stream it throws the exception .i know i have closed the bufferedOutputStream of the client socket but if i dont close that it gets stuck in the while loop of the server socket.
My aim is to sent data from the client to the server then display it and send that data back to the client and display it again .I have successfully sent the data to the server from the client and displayed it but i am unable to send it back to the client .What is wrong with my approach.I dont need a code i need to how data is sent and recieved without closing the connection.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: i have read it quite well ,this is not what i am asking dear,please at least read what i have asked

Comment: i have researched a lot for this and still it has been downgraded.such a pity

Answer (score 1):

Don't close the OutputStream in the client (`bout.close();`) (at least not before invoking `Socket.shutdownOutput()`, see below).

From the Javadoc of `Socket.getOutputStream()`:

> Returns an output stream for this socket.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the resulting output
>   stream delegates all of its operations to the channel.  If the channel
>   is in non-blocking mode then the output stream's write
>   operations will throw an
>   java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException.
>
> **Closing the returned OutputStream
>   will close the associated socket.**

If you want to indicate that you're done writing to the socket, call `Socket.shutdownOutput()` instead. It's Javadoc states:

`Socket.shutdownOutput()`:

> Disables the output stream for this socket. For a TCP socket, any
>   previously written data will be sent followed by TCP's normal
>   connection termination sequence.

After invoking Socket.shutdownOutput(), which waits for the data to be flushed, you can close the `OutputStream`, the `InputStream`, or the `Socket`. (it doesn't matter which you close - all three will end up closing the `Socket`)

Comment: My problem still prevails .The problem as i mentioned above is that my server socket is reading from its input stream correctly but when i flush the server sockets output stream i am unable to read it from the client sockets input stream,my application either reads from the server socket or it reads from the client socket .what i want is to read and display clients msg to the server and the the client to display the msg sent to the client by the server at the same time

Comment: when i comment the while loop in the client application it works fine but when i uncomment it it causes error and and while loop in the server application is not even executed.

Comment: What I said about the client also applies to the server code. Before invoking `cSocket.close()` on the server, invoke `cSocket.shutdownOutput()`. I just tested it here, it works fine out you invoke `Socket.shutdownOutput()` before closing the OutputStreams or the Socket.

Comment: let me post my code after doing what you said and you try to run it ,its not even going into the while loop of the server code .

Comment: check it out i have posted the edited code after what you told me to change.run it on your environment and see

Comment: it only prints the data sent back from the server and that too with skipping one letter each time

Comment: That's because you changed more than what I suggested. You also introduced a bug in the server because your changed `bout.write(c)` to  `bout.write(bin.read());`, so now you ignore every second character on the server side. Change that line back and it will work.

Comment: the problem still prevails brother .it now only displays the data recieved by the client sent from the serverand not the data recieved by the server sent from the client.it should execute the print statements of the both the server while loop as well as the client's while loop which it dosent

Comment: I don't think your current problems have anything to do with the problem that you mentioned in your question, which was that it throws an Exception. I don't understand what your current problem is, but it doesn't have a relation with Socket programming - it's just programming. I've answered your question, I believe.

Comment: no this problem is solely related with sockets , if you compile the code that i have edited you will then only understand what i am trying to say .your answer is not complete

Comment: You haven't fixed the bug in your code. How can I help you if you introduce extra bugs and then say that the problem is caused by my fix? I don't know what you are executing now.

Comment: i have edited the code ,copy paste it and try to run it.after you have run it ,comment the while loop in the client application and then re run it .then you will understand what i am telling you

Comment: The client prints `what is google` and the server prints `connection made`, then 'what is google' but each character on a new line, and then again `connection made`. That's exactly what you programmed it to do.